# How to handle client disconnect with PollingDuplexHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I am implementing a WCF service, with a Silverlight 3 client, which uses a PollingDuplexHttpBinding for communications.  What are the alternatives for handling when a client closes their browser without disconnecting from the server first?

I know that it will eventually throw a TimeoutException, which I can catch, but is there a better way of detecting this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like this:

```
OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += new EventHandler(Channel_Closed);
```

The channel also exposes a Faulted event, but the Closed event is thrown immediately afterwards.